# The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

when i try to run git-all-secrets i got Dockerfile: command not found
and this is the command include correct information

here is an example of the issue

```
root@momo22:/home/momo/git-all-secrets# docker run -it abhartiya/tools_gitallsecrets -token=9a8b60a10cf683f238e05 -org=bugcrwod
Command 'docker' is available in '/snap/bin/docker'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
docker: command not found
root@momo22:/home/momo/git-all-secrets#
```

Comment: what os? and what are the results of: "whereis docker"?

Comment: I have the same error when running docker on ubuntu 18.04 . I have chosen the docker to be installed during the installation of the server

Comment: I can confirm that even on Ubuntu 20.04 the case is consistent with the user above, docker gets installed into `/snap/bin` and not added to $PATH, see answers below on how to do it.

Answer (score 89):

### Temporary solution:

Run the command `export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin`

### Permanent solution:

Edit `/etc/environment` and add `/snap/bin` in the list then restart your system.

### Links

[answer for similar error with same fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/338728/925480)
[More info on /etc/enviroment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables)

Comment: No need to restart the system. Just use `source /etc/environment`

Comment: This /snap/bin already in /etc/environment list, I am trying to open project which stored on my external harddisk. If i open new terminal, and changing path to the directory, code . command working fine

Comment: Strange this has so many upvotes, as written this is incomplete and doesn't work especially if the environment file is empty. See Jay Harry's solution.

Answer (score 25):

you can add the path into .bashrc file

`$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin' >> ~/.bashrc`

open new terminal or execute this command

`$ source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: This solution only applies for Bash users. Other shells like Zsh require a similar, but different, approach.

Answer (score 19):

To fix this issue do the following:

1. Open the file `/etc/environment`.
2. Add `/snap/bin` to the end of the PATH Variable and concatenate using the `:` character.

   Example lets assume we had the PATH variable in the file was: `Path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"`

   After your update this will look like: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin`
3. Finally to update your shell and have the PATH variable ready to use, run `source /etc/environment`
4. Done

Comment: This is the best and most complete answer - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you come here and are just on `Ubuntu` rather than `docker` and you have just installed `snapd` without logging out/in again, log out then in again - you don't need to modify any files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `~/.bashrc` with nano or vim => `vim ~/.bashrc`
2. add `export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin` at the end of the file
3. log out from your user and log in again or reboot

if `~/.bashrc` doesn't exist:

1. create `~/.bashrc` file and open it => `touch ~/.bashrc && vim ~/.bashrc`
2. add `PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin`
3. logout from your user and login again or reboot

if you don't want to logout or reboot run these commands:

1. `sudo su ${USER}`
2. `bash`

Answer (score 0):

- open `~/.bash_profile`
- add `export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin` and save the changes
- run `source ~/.bash_profile`

you can open `~/.bash_profile` with `vi` or `gedit`